# write Chapter: word in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[square,sort&compress,comma,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{float,here}
\usepackage{color}

%\usepackage{lipsum}
%\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}


\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.1 cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{-0.28cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.65 cm }
\setlength{\textwidth}{6.4in}
\setlength{\textheight}{9.4in}

\input{rgb}
\pagestyle{myheadings}


\def\fps@figure{htbp}
\def\fps@table{htbp}

\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.5}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.4}
\newcommand{\FH}{{\textsc{\tiny FH}}}

\floatsep 36pt
\textfloatsep 36pt
\intextsep 36pt


\def\vitalsecdepth#1{\setcounter{secnumdepth}{#1}
   \setcounter{tocdepth}{#1}}
\vitalsecdepth{3} % 5/13/92 kelliher

\sloppy


\begin{document}


%\include{first-page}
%\include{statem}
%\include{certi1}
%\include{acknow2}

\clearpage
\baselineskip=20pt
%\include{TOC}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Table of Contents}

\newcommand{\setupname}[1][\chaptername]{
\titlecontents{chapter}[0pt]{\vspace{1ex}}{\bfseries#1~\thecontentslabel:\quad}{\bfseries}{\bfseries\hfill\contentspage}[]
}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\pagenumbering{roman}

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

%\chapter{Introduction}
\include{chap1}
\include{chap2}
\include{chap3}
\include{chap4}
\include{chap5}
\include{chap6}
\include{chap7}
\clearpage
\baselineskip=20pt
\pagenumbering{roman}
%\include{reference}


\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: Can you show what you've tried?